# 2d Look at Function

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I am creating a 2d sidescroller game. I have a point in space (where the mouse is) and I need the weapon to look and "follow" that point.

Does anyone know where to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wikihow: [How to Find the Angle Between Two Vectors](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors)

After you have the angle, you can appropriately rotate the thing to be rotated.

I am not sure if javascript also has an `atan2(x,y)` function, which could be used to get the angle.